# move and scale bounces back

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

As you can see in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3cI4nLksBw&9feature=youtu.be) it bounces back whenever I try to crop or move the crop box.  I can't find any way to do this and I think my code is correct. How am I suppose to do this?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                          message:@"Device has no camera"
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [myAlertView show];
  }
}

- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {
  UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  picker.delegate = self;
  picker.allowsEditing = YES;
  picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
  [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
  UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
  self.imageView.image = chosenImage;
  [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Ive updated my answer so beginners can understand.

Answer (score 0):

If image is too far away use this method to animate it back:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: animations: completion:]
```

animations: is a block and it will change e.g CGRects over a duration, if you want to change the image position you add `[image setRect:(CGRectMake(orginPosition.x, orginPosition.y, size.width, size.height))];`

completion: is a block but isn't required.

Comment: you can use Pythagorean theorem when you let go of the image and if the Pythagorean theorem is longer than you want use the method above... I shouldnt need to explain how to use it, its very simple

Comment: @arbitur, I don't believe you understand the question asked. The question is related to how the `UIImagePickerController` editing interface works. It has nothing to do with `UIView` animations.

Comment: Yes it is using UIImagePickerController

Comment: I thought the question was about how to get the UIImageView with the UIImage captured by the UIImagePickerController to bounce back when draged too far away.